# Javascript extract parts from string

Tags: javascript

I need to extract from this string  A =(0.5 -0.5 0.5) the first letter and the three number inside, how can I do? I thought to some regular expression but I don't know how.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: `str.replace(/[=()]/g,'').split(' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var string = "A =(0.5 -0.5 0.5)";

var parts = string.split('=');
var firstLetter = parts[0].trim();

var numbers = parts[1].replace('(', '').replace(')', '').split(' ');
```